# Azure VM Login using RBAC Role 'Virtual Machine User Login'

Tags: azure, rdp, rbac

Using the Azure portal to assign someone to a role of 'Virtual Machine User Login'.

[IAM Access control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q3Wp.png)
So forgive my ignorance here, the tool tip says 'Users with this role have the ability to login to the virtual machine as a regular user'.

Now I have tried RDP into this VM using the email and pass I use for the portal and it doesn't work. Am i missing a pre-req here? This is an isolated VM not on a domain, does it have to be? 
[RDP Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TLn8.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is for Linux VMs only.

[Log in to a Linux virtual machine in Azure using Azure Active Directory authentication (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/login-using-aad)

For Windows VMs, you have a few more steps

[Enable Azure Active Directory Domain Services using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started)

Comment: Thanks Bruno that makes sense!